# How to pass a variable into an internal function in Laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, function, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to pass the locale data to the eloquent query but it cannot get it. `$locale` value is taken from the URI.

```
class MyController extends Controller
{

    public function index($locale = 'en')
    {
        $news = News::join('categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'news.catid')
            ->select('news.*', 'categories.category')
            ->where([['news.published', '1'], ['news.deleted', '0']])
            ->where(function ($query) {
                $query->where('news.language', $locale) //$locale is not recognized naturally
                      ->orWhere('news.language', 'all');
            })
            ->orderBy('news.published_at', 'desc')
            ->take(4)
            ->get();

             .
             .
             .
    }
}
```

How can I pass `$locale` value into the subquery?

Comment: `function ($query) use ($locale) {`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is the `use` construct that you can use to create a *closure* around the variable:

```
->where(function ($query) use($locale) {
    $query->where('news.language', $locale) 
          ->orWhere('news.language', 'all');
})
```

See Example #3 in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php), "Inheriting variables from the parent scope".

Comment: Very good. Actually, I did not know about naming my problem in order to make a Google search. Thanks.